# Compare two resultsets and separate the matched and mismatched records in java

Tags: java

I have 2 databases one is oracle and other one is SAP HANA. I successfully connected to both the databases.

I want to compare the table data residing in these databases. I queried table A from Oracle lets say in resultset rs1 and queried table B from SAP HANA,say rs2.

Now I want to verify or compare one row from rs1 with each row in rs2, if row from rs1 equals with row from rs2, then separate that record like that every record should be compared and separated.

Comment: That should be easily done in an "If" block

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
rs1 = statement.executeQuery("select username from table1")
rs2 = statement1.executeQuery("select username from table2")

while(rs1.next()){
  // Compare till rs1 reach to it's last record.
  while(rs2.next()){
     if(){
       // Do your code here...
     }
  }

  // this will move resultSet cursor to first position.
  rs2.first();
}
```